# Multiple Named Views + Destroy $scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I am using a state with multiple views, how do I destroy one of the view's scopes? I tried the following and it did not work:

```
<div ng-if='showFilters' ui-view="filters"></div>
<div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
<div ui-view="graph"></div>
```

Even when $scope.showFilters set to false, the scope for the 'filters' view still exists. I wonder if the ng-if is only destroying its child scope, but doesn't know about the ui-view's scope. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you give a little more information/possible a plunkr? When you say the scope still exists, what do you mean? Values set in a child-state will persist in the parent state unless overridden, regardless of destroying the child states parent element. Also - what version of Angular and Ui-Router are you using?

Comment: I will put together a plunker right now. And I am not referencing values set in a child state...I agree with your sentiments there. What I am saying is setting the ng-if to false seemingly does not destroy the scope of the ui-view. I believe that is a whole different scope that is unrelated to the ng-if scope, so I'm trying to figure out a way in which setting the ng-if to false will destroy itself and its quasi-child 'filters' scope. Angular version is 1.2.27 and Ui-Router is 0.2.15

Comment: plunkr seems to be kinda hard with the multiple views I am trying to demonstrate...I guess the root of my question is, how to get ng-if to affect the scope created by ui-view. If ng-if is false, it still doesn't destroy the scope tied to the 'filters' view. I know this because It is still receiving messages that it $on's from a $broadcast from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a hierarchy of views so you can easily destroy the scope of any 'child' view:

```
.state('parent', {
        controller: "parentController as parent",
        templateUrl: '../parent.html'
    })
.state('child1', {
        controller: "child1Controller",
        templateUrl: '../child1.html'
    })
.state('child2', {
        controller: "child2Controller",
        templateUrl: '../child2.html'
    })
```

Note that you don't have to use 'parent.child2' (nested states) unless you want to. The key is that the child scopes will inherit the parent scope as long as they are within the html frame of the parent, such as:

```
<div ui-view="parent">
   <div ui-view="child1"></div>
   <div ui-view="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Then from the children, you can simply reference something like `{{parent.filters.filter1}}` and if you need to destroy the scope, you can do so from the parent controller using `this.filters = undefined`.